# Finding a sequence of continuous real-valued functions on [0,1] whose limit function is discontinuous on an infinite number of points.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I am working on the problem: Find a sequence of continuous real-valued functions on [0,1] whose limit function is discontinuous on an infinite number of points.

I would like to find an example of a sequence of continuous functions converging to $1 - \frac {1}{2^n}$ so that I can have an infinitely discontinuous limit function. Other suggestions of any such function would also be appreciated.

Comment: Let's use $x \in [0,1]$ to index the domain of these functions and $n \in \Bbb{N}$ to index a sequence of functions.  On which infinite set of $x$s is your proposed $1 - 2^{-n}$ discontinuous?

Comment: I'm looking for a sequence of functions with a limit function that equals $1-{2^-n}$ for all $x = 1-2^{-n}$ and 0 for all other x? Sorry, I'm confused by your question.

Comment: If $f_n(x) = 1 - 2^{-n}$, $f_n(x)$ is constant and $f(x) = 1$ has no discontinuities.  If $f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 1 ,& x = 1-2^{-n} \\ 0 ,& x \neq 1-2^{-n} \end{cases}$, then $f = \begin{cases} 0 ,& x<1 \\ 1 ,& x = 1 \end{cases}$ again does not have infinitely many discontinuities.  On which infinite set of $x$'s did you want $f$ to have discontinuities?

Comment: I see, thank you. $x$ should have infinitely many discontinuities on $[0, 1]$, as $f$ maps from $[0, 1]$ to reals. I was thinking of first determining an infinitely discontinuous limit function that is discontinuous on all rationals or something like that. Not sure if this is the correct approach.